# How prove how many 1's in a binary representation?

Tags: induction, recursion, binary

Let  $ b: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ the function given by

$b(n) = \begin{cases}
0&n=0
\\b\left(\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor\right)
+ (n\mod 2) &n>0\end{cases}$

$ \bullet $ How to prove that the number of 1 in the binary representation of n is b(n), for every $n>0$?

$ \bullet $ How to prove that $ b(n) \le\lfloor{log_2 n}\rfloor $, for every $ n > 0 $

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried, say, induction? Or *anything*, really? (I see you are new: it may be useful to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.)

Comment: Thanks, Clement. I tried dividing the problem into even and odd numbers but can't finish with a classy answer.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: For the first part, suppose that $n=(b_mb_{m-1}\ldots b_0)_{\text{two}}$; then

$$\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor=(b_mb_{m-1}\ldots b_1)_{\text{two}}\;,$$

and clearly

$$b(n)=b\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor\right)+b_0\;.$$

For the second, how many times can you divide an integer $n$ by $2$, throwing away any remainder each time?